# How do I set meta tags in Nuxt SSR?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, seo, server-side-rendering, meta-tags

I've been trying to set up some dynamic meta tags for my Nuxt SSR project following the [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo/). Surprisingly neither having `head` property as an object, not using it as a function did not result in meta tags displaying properly when I view page source. Link preview doesn't work either.

Here's my `head` object in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
head: {
    title: 'Somesite',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'og:site_name', property: 'og:site_name', content: 'Somesite' },
      { hid: 'og:type', property: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },
```

And here's what I have in my pages:

```
head() {
    return {
      title: 'Some title',
      meta: [
        {
          property: 'og:title',
          content: 'Some title',
        },
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: 'Some description',
        },
        {
          property: 'og:description',
          content: 'Some description',
        },
        {
          property: 'og:image',
          content:
            'https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--arLlmpvP--/c_imagga_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,h_420,q_auto,w_1000/https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/articles/1xgexxq7w0ejq02zqd5r.png',
        },
        {
          property: 'og:url',
          content: 'http://google.com/',
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:site',
          name: 'twitter:site',
          content: '@sometwitter',
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:description',
          name: 'twitter:description',
          content: 'Some description',
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:creator',
          name: 'twitter:creator',
          content: '@sometwitter',
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:title',
          name: 'twitter:title',
          content: 'Some title',
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:card',
          name: 'twitter:card',
          content: 'summary',
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:image',
          name: 'twitter:image',
          content:
            'https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--arLlmpvP--/c_imagga_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,h_420,q_auto,w_1000/https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/articles/1xgexxq7w0ejq02zqd5r.png',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
```

The `title` works fine but not the meta tags. Here's what I see when I view page source:

```
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="description" name="description" content="## Build Setup">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og:title" name="og:title" property="og:title" content="bamboo">
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og:description" name="og:description" property="og:description" content="## Build Setup">
```

Side note: I wasn't even able to determine where `## Build Setup` comes from.

Interestingly though, when I inspect component in Vue Devtools I see correct meta info (screenshot).
[image: Vue Devtools screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I didn't konw why. But I just think if every meta needs a only name, so I add a ‘hid’ attribute for every meta, and I solve this problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWP2p.png)

Comment: I think it would be more useful for users from the future if you share code as formatted code in your answer rather than in an image :)